# Get only one element in class for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have the following used for Google Maps using its Javascript API:

```
# HTML markup
<div id="#city_123">
  <div class="map"></div>
</div>

# calling function
marker("#city_123 .map"); // There is only one .map

# marker() function
function marker(shop) {
  var map;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  $(shop).each(function(index) {  
    map = new google.maps.Map(this, mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data("lat"), $(this).data("lng")),
      map: map,
    });

    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

  });
}
```

I have tried numerous ways to remove the `.each` because it is not necessary. I only have one `.map`. There are reasons why I must use `.map` class because it's actually created dynamically, but that besides the point.

How can I rewrite this to be friendly?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: It's called dynamically. Everytime I click a button, a new map should produce. Too much effort to reproduce in jsfiddle.net. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

## JS

```
function marker(shop) {
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($(shop)[0], mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng($(shop).data("lat"), $(shop).data("lng")),
        map: map,
    });
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}
```